# android: response from market activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, google-play

I am trying to make an app that opens android market page of selected app & lets user download it.I have used below intent to open market.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData (Uri.parse ("market://details?id=" + PackageName ));
    intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult (intent, 13);
```

but I always get resultcode 0 in onActivityResult.StackTrace says:

```
I/ActivityManager(   79): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.an
droid.vending/.AssetInfoActivity }
W/ActivityManager(   79): Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result.
```

What I want is that market returns me some response that user downloaded the app or just cancelled.

**EDIT:** @CommonsWare I am trying to access added package here But cant figure what should be key to get packagename from extras of ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Do this when the system sends the intent
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    String packagename = b.get(?);   //cant figure what should be key to get packagename //from extras
    }

}
```

Comment: i believe you would be looking for `requestCode` and not `resultCode` in the `onActivityResult` method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Android Market is not set up to support `startActivityForResult()`. Also, bear in mind that the download and installation happen asynchronously (i.e., user clicks Install, and the download occurs in the background, and they finish the install via the `Notification`).

Comment: Does that mean there is no other way to get currently installed app than to query whole installed list each time on PACKAGE_ADDED?

Comment: @Saurabh: There are extras on the `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcast that will help you identify what was added.

Comment: I followed this post to get extras http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990855/android-how-to-get-location-information-from-intent-bundle-extras-when-using-loc but fail to get key for Packagename.See edited post above.

Comment: @Saurabh: Use `PackageManager` and `getPackagesForUid()` to get the packages associated with the UID you get via `EXTRA_UID` in the `Intent`.

Answer (score 3):

@CommonsWare Superb!

Your solution proved helpful & it also landed me to another very useful page http://devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/com/android/internal/content/PackageMonitor.java.shtml

Below is a code snippet from above link source to get package name of currently installed app from broadcast intent:

```
 String getPackageName(Intent intent) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String pkg = uri != null ? uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() : null;
        return pkg;
    }
```

Thanks Commonsware.