# how to get Updated location & Disable GPS after getting it in android?

Tags: android

friends,

i am using following code to get GPS location

it is causing two problems

1) when my location is changed / I move my phone from one area to another I dont get updated gps location(latitude/longitude)

2) after getting gps location my gps of phone is enabled how to disable it?

```
 double MyDeviceLatitude,MyDeviceLongitude;

public void GetGPSLocation()
{

 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

                       LocationListener myLocationListener = new CurrentLocationListener(); 

                       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30, 30, myLocationListener);

                   Location   currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps"); 

if(currentLocation != null)
                       {

                       MyDeviceLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                       MyDeviceLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
}else
{

 currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("network");
 MyDeviceLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
 MyDeviceLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();



}



public class CurrentLocationListener implements LocationListener{

            public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) 
            {
                if (argLocation != null) 
                {
                    MyDeviceLatitude = argLocation.getLatitude();
                    MyDeviceLongitude = argLocation.getLongitude();
                }

            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle arg2) {
            }
            }
```

}

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UMMA Do check this similar post that uses a Broadcast receiver thats seems to solve your problem [Android: How to get location information from intent bundle extras when using LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990855/android-how-to-get-location-information-from-intent-bundle-extras-when-using-loc)

Comment: example is not complete so i cannot implement this :(

Comment: @UMMA you need to create a LocationReceiver (that extends BroadcastReceiver) & add that to your manifest as mentioned in the link.Do read guides on how to integrate this BroadcastReceiver with your Activity/Service. You may pass obtained location to your Activity/Service.