# what is the persistance of LocationManager registration

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location, android-pendingintent

Lets say I have an `app` and within its activity I will register `pendingIntent` with `LocationManager` to be triggered every 10mins.

like in this example : 
[Android: How to get location information from intent bundle extras when using LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990855/android-how-to-get-location-information-from-intent-bundle-extras-when-using-lo)

If user closes the `app` will the `LocationManager` still keep firing `pendingIntent` ?

so that I can invoke notification from `BroadcastReciver` (manifest ver) of my app for this `pendingIntent` when my app is not running.

If yes, then when the LocationManager is actually cleaned, after phone restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want reliable location updates after the app exits, please consider using `AlarmManager` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)) to wake up the device every 10 minutes. Register and unregister your location listener each time the alarm fires so that the GPS can be otherwise idle.

You may also want to use something like `WakefulIntentService` (see [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)) so that the device will stay awake while your app is waiting for a location update. Android will interrupt your `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive()` method if it takes too long and isn't holding a `WakeLock`.